# jQuery Ajax with POST to send string doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have already seen all the q&a here, and I couldn't fix the problem.
I'm trying to send a two character string.

```js
var country_code = 'PT';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'GetData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'country': country_code},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      ...
    },
    error: function () {                    
      console.log("There was an error");
  }
});
```

on GetData.php I just have

```php
$cty = $_POST['country'];

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT uuid_client, country FROM users_insertions WHERE country='".$cty."'";
...
echo json_encode($res);
```

Though, it doesn’t work. I can't get the string on GetData.php
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error? try to use `die($_POST['country'])` and check your console.

Comment: code works perfectly fine, Where's the problem?

Comment: I found the problem, really weird. It has to do with the URL as I made some changes in the .htaccess root file: "Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: How can the "RewriteEngine On" in .htaccess Apache file affect this issue?

Comment: Weird stuff from Apache!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not have any serious problem, but I think It's better to use `data: {country: country_code}` instead of `data: {'country': country_code}`. Maybe this can solve your problem.

Comment: Please inspect your browser's console and tell the result.

Comment: Do you mean with Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
It was the [Apache .htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) that was changing the URL to something else.
If nothing else works, try checking your .htaccess file.